# Runtime error when using InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa2.2

I want to access Structure Group metadata in my DXA 2.2 java page models. Following the [DXA documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/571231/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/r2-data-model-builders) I have added the `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder` model builder to the pipeline in my Page Rendering TBB. When previewing the page, I see that Structure Group metadata is present in the page JSON. I also see following additional json field.

```
"ExtensionData": {
    "Schemas": {
      "$type": "RichTextData[]",
      "$values": [
        {
          "Fragments": [
            "313729"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

However, on the on my DXA application side, I get the following runtime error when I access a page:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.RichTextData cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.getInheritedSemanticSchemas(DefaultModelBuilder.java:168)
```

It seems `DefaultModelBuilder` is not able to parse 'ExtensionData' element of the PageModelData. It is clearly expecting String object instead of RichTextData. ExtensionData is something added by `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder` itself, so I have no control over it.

Did I miss something or is it's a DXA bug?

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @Sahid, I'm trying to reproduce this issue in OOTB DXA 2.2, for me, the ExtensionData type value getting string instead of RichTextData. look at this GetTypedArrayOfValues code logic https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/ed850db1ca89a6bd81992791f57c9d99d8d6bc19/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DataModelBuilder.cs#L160, for me getting the schema as List<string>,  which is expected. I don't understand how it's for you to get RichTextData. can you explain how is your SG metadata schema looks and how it's configured on your current published page.

Comment: @Velmurugan, it is indeed very strange that ExtensionData has a list of RichTextData in my case. As the class [InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/ed850db1ca89a6bd81992791f57c9d99d8d6bc19/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder.cs) explicitly creates a list<string> for the schema ids.   Let me further dig into this...

Comment: @Velmurugan, I found out the reason of the issue, please check my answer.

Comment: Good to know, you can accept your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that CMS side of DXA 2.2 for SDL Web 8.5 has a bug (or incompatibility with Java DXA 2.2 side) which is causing values of `Schemas` to be generated as a `List<RichTextData>` instead of `List<String>` in the `ExtensionData` of the JSON page model.

As in our case, `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilderi` is using the method `GetTypedArrayOfValues` which doesn't  have this following vital line which is responsible for creating a `List<String>` for Schema Ids.

`if (strings.Count == fieldValues.Count) return strings.ToArray();`

(For example, [this](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/8cf9f302e59d870434a4ff517c75a9d574295895/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DataModelBuilder.cs) version of method: `GetTypedArrayOfValues` doesn't have this statement.)

Later releases for DXA CMS have already [fixed](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/ed850db1ca89a6bd81992791f57c9d99d8d6bc19/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DataModelBuilder.cs#L160) this issue and it is delivered with the 9.x CMS versions. As Velu also pointed out he is seeing the expected behaviour.

For those who happen to use 8.5 CMS with DXA 2.2 version, this issue can be addressed by a simple fix (just adding a missing statement, as stated above). Or perhaps a fix-release is already available.